# Are questions about statistics from a politician's statement on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Many political statements include statistics and I generally like to see if there is any truth to those statistics. While the truthfulness of the statement as a whole could be pretty subjective, I think most statistics can be analyzed objectively. Is it considered on-topic to ask about specific statistics used in political statements?

Comment: If the statement is in any way notable, Skeptics.SE would be ontopic to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know where they got their statistics from, I'd certainly consider that on topic.  An answer to that question would help you make sense of what a politician is saying and what their positions are.

Be careful though, If you know where a politician is getting their statistics from, but you want to otherwise fact check their source, then you might find yourself in a situation where you have numerous other sources either affirming or debunking those statistics, and it is very possible for that question to be **too broad**

Comment: In this case, if I were to ask "Was the impact of the proposed tax cut cited by a Presidential candidate from a recent Harvard study factually accurate?" would that be too broad?

Comment: @LearnWorkLearn You're asking us to fact check the study, so yes.

Comment: Makes sense, I agree.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to fact-check a statement made by a politician, then this is a better question for the website [Skeptics Stackexchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/). It specializes on verifying claims by notable people or organizations.